# navigation tutorial dependencies

Tags: ros, navigation, tutorials, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done the URDF tutorial and have a model of my robot. I also have a neato lidar sensor publishing data using http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver. Odometry is being published by the Serializer package.

My question is in the Navigation tutorial it says to do a
"roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep"

What do I put in for
"my_tf_configuration_dep"
"my_odom_configuration_dep"
and "my_sensor_configuration_dep"

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10775/navigation-tutorial-dependencies/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ringo,

I believe these refer to packages you already use for your sensors (e.g. your [xv11 laser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver)), odometry data (your [serializer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/serializer)) and your URDF description which may or may not be in its own packge (e.g. my_robot_description).  So one possibility in your case would be:

```
$ roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base xv_11_laser_driver serializer my_robot_description
```

If you already have a working package for your robot (e.g my_robot_package) that itself depends on the xv_11_laser_driver and serializer packages as well as your URDF description, you could use:

```
$ roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_robot_package
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on 2011-08-04**:
Thanks. Do you happen to have a launch file that works for the navigation tutorial I can use for a template. I'm not sure exactly what to put for things like odom_node_type, transform_configuration_type, etc.